# No me conecta mi visual studio a sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

mi problema es el siguiente no puedo conectar ningun proyecto q tenia, intente el visual studio 2019 y sql 2017 no funciono, cambie a sql server 2015 y visual 2015 q es donde se desarrollo los programas en windows forms, pero sigue sin darme la conexion

Este es el error cada vez que intento acceder por medio de un login

---

INFORMACIÓN ADICIONAL:
Información adicional: Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - No se pudo abrir una conexión con SQL Server)

Ya intente  iniciando los servicios y estan iniciados, desde su administrador del sql server solo el sql agent (No se si sea el erro) no inicia, tambien busque como hacerlo iniciar y no me funciono

esta es la cadena de conexion q uso mayormente para acceder, intente colocando el nombre del servidor y nada

public SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Server=.;DataBase=DemoPractica;Integrated Security=SSPI");

Gracias por leer

Comment: Desde el Sql Server Management Studio puede conectarte ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini si desde ahi sin problemas, mi bd esta creada con sus respectivas tablas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendaria intentaste creando un archivo `.udl` para testear la conexion

[Crear un archivo de vínculo de datos universal (UDL) para probar la conectividad](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/troubleshooting/ad-fs-tshoot-sql#create-a-universal-data-link-udl-file-to-test-connectivity)

Basicamente creas un archivo de texto y le cambias la extension a `.udl`. Luego ingresas los datos y validas la conexion, si todo pasa correctamente entonces editas ese archivo con el `notepad` y tendras el `connection string` correcto que debes usar en tu codigo.

[Trick - How to get Database Connection String using NotePad](https://dotnetcookie.blogspot.com/2013/10/cnet-trick-how-to-get-easily-connection.html)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por supuesto a ese connection string le debes quitar la parte del Provider ya que al usas la libreria de `SqlConnection` esto ya esta implicito

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias @LeandroTuttini Ya pude ingresar a mi proyecto intentare probar con otros, tengo dos preguntas, si me las puedes aclarar, por favor. Por que sucede este error ? y tengo que hacer el mismo procedimiento cada vez que necesite abrir un proyecto nuevo ?

Comment: Pero desde el udl obtuviste un connection string diferente al que venias utilizando? en principio si los datos de conexion no son correctos no lograras la conexion. Si tienes otro proyecto solo debes usar los datos correctos para conectarte

Comment: Si era diferente, con el connection string anterior solia conectarme normal antes, formatee el equipo e instale el visual y sql y me trajo este error, ahora hice lo que mandaste y me dio bien, solo que no entiendo el por que no acepta mi connection string anterior

Comment: comparalo y revisa la diferencia, si reinstalaste puede que algun nombre del servidor haya cambiado